# Specify scope with in xml free configuration

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I use `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` to configure my application. How I can specify bean scope using annotations or in other xml-free way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different Types of scope:

singleton – Return a single bean instance per Spring IoC container

prototype – Return a new bean instance each time when requested

request – Return a single bean instance per HTTP request. *

session – Return a single bean instance per HTTP session. *

globalSession – Return a single bean instance per global HTTP session. *

XML-Free Way:

```
@Scope("[scopegoeshere]")
public class myClass {}
```